# Setting Custom Email Headers

Tags: email

I need to provide an email form on my website that'll email members. I want to be able to set custom mail headers before the email is sent (I'm using Mandrill, so custom headers allow me additional features). I don't see anything in the docs about custom mail headers: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/email.html

Is this possible to do in EE?

**UPDATE 1:**

I created an extension. And looking at this: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/email/index.html -- it seems I should be able to set the headers by manipulating `$data['headers']`. I have this in my extension:

```
function email_send(&$data)
{       
    $data['subject']        = 'Hello World';
    $data['headers']['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

When I receive the email, the subject is "Hello World". However, when I look at the headers, I do not see `foo` => `bar` in it. I've checked with my host to see if there is anything that the hosting might be doing to strip custom headers. They claim no. So, the next question: **is there anything in EE that might be preventing me from setting custom headers?**

I'm currently configured to use PHP Mail, but I do want to use SMTP for this eventually.

**UPDATE 2:**

When I configure CPanel to use either `Sendmail` or `SMTP`, the subject does not get set to "Hello World". Instead, it says "Contact Form Email". Summary:

1. Subject only gets set when in PHP Mail
2. Email headers not set in PHP Mail, Sendmail, or SMTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ee()->email->set_header($header, $value);
```

This isn't documented anywhere, but I see this function in CodeIgniter's Email library (which EE Email library extends), so I assume it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in CodeIgniter's Email library. You'll see that in many places the `header_str` is used, not the whole `headers` array. So you'd have to add to the `header_str` instead.

As for sending with other methods, you'll see that the `subject` is never used with SMTP or Sendmail - instead those assume that the subject is already in the `header_str`.

Shameless plug: my [Escort add-on](http://amphibian.info/software/ee/escort) allows you to easily send email with Mandrill (and other services) and offers a simple hook to add any data you want to your email before it gets sent (see [escort_pre_send](http://amphibian.info/software/ee/escort#hooks) extension hook). E.g.,

```
function escort_pre_send($service, $data)
{
    if($service == 'mandrill')
    {
        $data['headers']['foo'] = 'bar';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to integrate with Mandrill! Let me digest what you wrote here and take a look at your add-on. Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi Derek, I purchased your addon and have installed it. I have verified in the headers that the addon is indeed being used. How do I set custom headers? Do you have documentation I can reference? Thanks!

Comment: I just added a code example to my answer.